# How to convert this code to a "for" loop?

Tags: c++, for-loop

Any ideas how to make below assignments in one "for" loop?
Fe. to assign p[8].cz = p[1].cp + p[2].cp + p[3].cp + ... + p[8].cp;

```
p[1].cz=p[1].cp;
p[2].cz=p[1].cp+p[2].cp;
p[3].cz=p[1].cp+p[2].cp+p[3].cp;
p[4].cz=p[1].cp+p[2].cp+p[3].cp+p[4].cp;
```

Comment: Consider the relation between two adjacent elements. BTW: Indices in C++ start with zero, not one, in case you didn't know.

Comment: What is the value of `p[0].cz`?

Answer (score 3):

Something like this, perhaps:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i=1; i <= 8; ++i) {
  p[i].cz = sum += p[i].cp;
}
```

Comment: Assuming `p[0].cz = 0`, then you can do `p[i].cz = p[i-1].cz + p[i].cp;`

Comment: @smac89 Yes, but that wouldn't be equivalent to the OP's example, and I didn't want to make additional assumptions.

Comment: @smac89 Not bad, but get rid of the assumption. Then make a separate answer. It can be better than this one.